# Android too many sub view in screen --> slow down Keyboard hidden

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a View that contains a table view custom table which is  complicated: each row has about 10 views (EditText, Label, Checkbox).
The Table has 10 rows in total.

My problem is that when the user focuses on edittext, the keyboard shows (everything is ok), but when the keyboard hides, the response is too slow: the first time the app has a delay of 2s, the second time the keyboard disappears and a black screen is shown behind the keyboard, after that the View has turn to its normal state

I try to set activity's `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, but no luck

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?